# Add dynamic ID to a table cell in ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic, html-table

I'm looping this TR, it's being repeated 5 times.
I want to use DYNAMIC ID for each cell ( so that ID of the cells of the first row should be different than the ID of the cells of second row and so on).

**MY CODE :-**

```
<% @timesheetconsultants.each do |timesheetconsultant| %> 
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="MonR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tueR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wedR"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thuR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="friR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="satR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sunR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
```

**IT IS PRINTING THE TABLE THIS WAY**

```
<table>
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="MonR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tueR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wedR"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thuR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="friR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="satR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sunR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="MonR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tueR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wedR"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thuR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="friR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="satR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sunR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

**BUT I WANT THIS TABLE LIKE THIS**

```
<table>
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="MonR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tueR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wedR"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thuR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="friR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="satR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sunR"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="MonOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tueOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wedOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thuOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="friOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="satOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sunOt"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

make use of index of array to make the id unique. try this

```
<% @timesheetconsultants.each_with_index do |timesheetconsultant,i| %> 
          <tr>            
            <td><%= timesheetconsultant.HourType %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'monR')" id="Mon<%=i%>"<%= timesheetconsultant.Mo %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'tueR')" id="tue<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.Tu %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'wedR')" id="wed<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.We %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'thuR')" id="thu<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.Th %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'friR')" id="fri<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.Fr %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'satR')" id="sat<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.Sa %></td>
            <td onclick="showlayer('time-picker',this,'sunR')" id="sun<%=i%>"><%= timesheetconsultant.Su %></td>
            <td id="totalR"><%= timesheetconsultant.TotalHour %></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
```